# "Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined" - scroll down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

"Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined"

I'm trying to setup a page scroll-down

here's the jquery:

```
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
 <script>

 (function ($){

 $('navbar').on('click', 'li.a', function () {
 var $clickedAnchor = $(this),
$panelToScrollTo = $('#' + $clickedAnchor.data('loc'));
$panelToScrollTo.scrollTo();
});

}(jquery));

 </script>
```

Here's the menu:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" data-loc="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-loc="dg">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-loc="bg">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-loc="tm">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-loc="fun">Plans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-loc="contact-form">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: change `jquery` to `jQuery`

Answer (score 1):

You have a case sensitive issue replace **jquery** by **jQuery** in the last line of your script.

Comment: thanks, no more error. Unfortunately scroll down still doesn't work

Comment: Try checking out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
}(jquery));
```

To:

```
}(jQuery));
```